# A matrix function defined in terms of partitions and hafnians

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, symmetric-matrices

I am curious to know if the following function $f$ defined for a complex-symmetric matrix $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{M} \in \mathbb{C}^{r \times r}$ has a name or has been studied previously
\begin{align}
f(\mathbf{M}) = \sum_{\pi\in P''([r])}\left(|\pi|-1\right)!(-1)^{|\pi|-1}\prod_{\mathbf{\beta} \in \pi} |\text{haf} \ \mathbf{M}[\mathbf{\beta}]|^2,
\end{align}
Here $P''([r])$ is the set of partitions of the first $r$ integers excluding partitions that have parts of odd length. $\pi$ is a partition of the integers $\{1,2,3,\ldots,r\}$ that does not a part of odd length and $|\pi|$ is the number of parts in the partition. For example if $r=4$ then
\begin{align}
P([4]) = \{ \{ 1,2,3,4\},\{1,2|3,4\},\{1,3|2,4\}, \{1,4|2,3\} \}
\end{align}
And thus for example when $\pi = \{1,2|3,4\}$, $|\pi| = 2$ then $\beta$ can be either {1,2} or {3,4}.

The hafnian is defined here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafnian
and the notation $\mathbf{M}[\beta]$ is used to indicate the matrix obtained from $\mathbf{M}$ by keeping the rows and columns in $\beta$. Thus for example if $r=4$ then $\mathbf{M}[\{1,3\}] = \begin{pmatrix} M_{1,1} & M_{1,3} \\ M_{1,3} & M_{3,3} \end{pmatrix}$.

Note that the hafnian of an odd sized matrix is zero and so is $f$ when applied to an odd-sized matrix.

The first few evaluations for $r=2,4$ give
\begin{align}
f(\mathbf{M_{2\times2}}) &= \overline{M_{1, 2}} M_{1, 2} \\
f(\mathbf{M_{4\times4}}) &= \overline{M_{1, 2}} \overline{M_{3, 4}} M_{1, 3} M_{2, 4} + \overline{M_{1, 2}} \overline{M_{3, 4}} M_{1, 4} M_{2, 3} + \overline{M_{1, 3}} \overline{M_{2, 4}} M_{1, 2} M_{3, 4} + \overline{M_{1, 3}} \overline{M_{2, 4}} M_{1, 4} M_{2, 3} + \overline{M_{1, 4}} \overline{M_{2, 3}} M_{1, 2} M_{3, 4} + \overline{M_{1, 4}} \overline{M_{2, 3}} M_{1, 3} M_{2, 4}.
\end{align}
where we use overline for complex conjugation.

Some numerical checks (up to r=10) suggest that the number of terms for an $r \times r$ matrix is $(r-1)!$ and that each of the terms is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $r$ in the entries of $M$ (and its complex conjugate) with coefficient equal to one despite the appearance of the factorial and negative signs in the definition of $f$.